# azure 2012 management services staging

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2012, azure

I have a website set up with a staging slot on Azure Websites. I am having trouble getting web deployment to work from Visual Studio 2012.  I keep getting this error when I try to publish to staging or production:

> Error  23  Web deployment task failed. (Could not connect to the remote computer ("[MYSITENAME].scm.azurewebsites.net") using the specified process ("Web Management Service") because the server did not respond. Make sure that the process ("Web Management Service") is started on the remote computer.  Learn more at: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=221672#ERROR_COULD_NOT_CONNECT_TO_REMOTESVC.)

When I go to publish, I select the staging site (or even the regular site) from the profile list dropdown. I "Validate Connection" and that turns out just fine. In the Settings area, under Databases, there are 2 options with the same name for each of the connections which is a bit odd.

Can anyone help? Thank you!

Comment: I got the same.  Have a staging site on website in Azure with CD (production on own box).  Its been fine for a couple of months.. today the site just hangs, and doing builds gets this error.